# Getting attribute option values

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute

I have added a customer attribute for customers to select languages that they are fluent in using a multiselect input. I'm trying to get them to display on the frontend but can only get the ID's to display.

Right now I'm using a query in the block to grab the actual labels, but would much prefer if there were an easier way to grab the values instead.

What I'm doing currently:

```
$langattrA = $customer->getData('customer_languages');

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$attTable = $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option_value');

$query = "SELECT value FROM $attTable WHERE option_id in ($langattrA)";
$result = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

The downfall of this is also that using `fetchAll()` returns "Array" instead of the actual list of selected languages.

Using `print_r($result)` is also messy.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: If you need a comma seperated list, why not use `implode()`?

Comment: @sv3n I’ve tried using implode on the array I get from using print_r($array) but it doesn’t seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: I've read your answer ... if it works OK, but it does not look really correct to me. I've i got you right, you have a custom customer multiselect attribute and want to display a dropdown in a .phtml? If so, maybe you want to add your template file (and other related code) ... maybe someone has a better idea :)

Comment: I didn't want to display a dropdown, but rather just list the selected attributes the customer chose. The editable customer attribute is a multiselect (can choose from various languages). I wanted to display the chosen languages of that customer in another spot on my site. The original issue was that calling the chosen languages would only show the value_id's (201, 202, 203, etc) rather than the actual value (English, Spanish, Chinese, etc).  Using the code given by Keyur, along with implode() gave me the comma-separated list of value's.

Comment: Ah, ok ... so it seems to be solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a combination of implode and the above answer to get it working. So thanks to both sv3n and Keyur.

I used the following bit to get the specific customer's selected list of chosen languages (their ID's).

```
$langAtt = $customer->getData('customer_languages');
```

I used Keyur's first bit of code to get the option values of the specific customer's languages:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer','customer_languages');

if($attribute->getSource()){
 $optionValue = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($langAtt); 
}
```

Then used the following to list the array:

```
$att = implode(", ", $optionValue);
echo $att;
```

Thank you both again!

Comment: You can accept your answer If you found the solution to clean the community :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get it like this,

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer','YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

if($attribute->getSource()){
     $optionValue = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText(1); // whrer 1 is id you can replace with your
}
```

---

If you want all your option then you can get it by,

```
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Comment: Both of these still return "Array", rather than the actual comma-separated list of values. If I insert just one single ID (ex:  `getOptionText(202)`), then I'll get the value, but this is a multi-select attribute, so I'm inserting multiple ID's.

Comment: Default method of magento will surely return of array, if you want comma separated then you need to create own method @taskle

Comment: I am sorry but I am not getting you @sv3n

Comment: Someone downvoted your answer and I dont understand why - so I upvoted for it :)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for supporting :) If someone want to downvote then he/she give reason. and I think nothing wrong in my answer :) @sv3n